# Not able to install any bittorrent client

Tags: bittorrent

I cant download any of the bittorrent clients online

```
kristoffer@HP-Stream-Laptop-14-ax0XX:~$ sudo apt-get install rTorrent
[sudo] password for kristoffer: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rTorrent
kristoffer@HP-Stream-Laptop-14-ax0XX:~$
```

Comment: case is significant on any posix (*nix) system  (ie. unix, osx, ios, gnu, aix, ...)

Comment: Ubuntu ships with a torrent client installed by default: `transmission`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can do `export LANG=C` beore running a command to get the output in english.

The reason you can't install the package `rTorrent` is that the name of the package is rtorrent.

You can search for a package using the command `apt-cache search rtorrent`, which would show you the following:

```
$ apt-cache search rtorrent
qbittorrent-nox - bittorrent client based on libtorrent-rasterbar (without X support)
rtgui - Web based front-end for rTorrent
rtorrent - ncurses BitTorrent client based on LibTorrent from rakshasa
rtpg-www - web based front end for rTorrent
```

You can install rtorrent by running `sudo apt-get install rtorrent` (note the lower case).

As per your update, you have already installed rtorrent, and can start it by running `rtorrent` in a terminal. It additionally seems that you have missing dependencies. Please try what the output suggests; `sudo apt-get -f install`. Usually this will install the needed package.